# Proxy/Link –> Problem seeing colored Proxy rig over black Linked rig

Tags: rigging, linked-data

Hi blender stackexchange community!

I'm trying to Link my rigged character into a blank animation scene for the first time, to be able to rework my source scene in the future and get updates in all my animation scenes.

The collection-linking process works, then I create a proxy of the rig selecting only the Armature (that works too). My problem is that when I'm in Pose mode with the Proxy only selected, The black linked-collection (and rig) overlaps over my colored Proxy-rig (the "Bone Groups" colors I initially chose in my source scene). I actually somehow see some of the colored controllers(bones), but not the others.

That's the original colored Armature:

[image]

And that's when I show the linked-collection:

[image]

Is there a way to hide all the rigging stuff in the black linked-collection and only keep the geometry shown, so that the colored Proxy-rig controllers are the only ones showing up?

I tried to make the Proxy "In front" of the Linked-collection, but it doesn't work. And If I hide the linked-collection, I'm missing the geometry.

Thank you very much for your feedback!

Carl

Answer (score 3):

I think I have the answer (sorry for English, it's not my main language). All you have to do is disable the rig in the viewport (hide too). Save the file. Then follow the steps you did before (link colecction and make proxy) and you are done.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Amazing Joel! Thank you! I will try that soon! :)

Answer (score 0):

Select your proxy and go to Object Properties -> Viewport Display and put your Proxy **in Front** and display as **Solid**. Let me know, if this solved your problem.

[image]

Comment: THanks Atkay, I'll try that!